# How to create integration test for app with Firebase Auth?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I created a Flutter app. My app uses Firebase Auth.
I need to create integration tests for my app, but I don’t know how to do this if I need to enter my login and password.
I'm new to flutter and this is a problem for me. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For integration testing, Flutter provides [`FlutterDriver`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver-class.html).
To get started, you can view the [official guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction).

Once you are familiar with how `FlutterDriver` works, you will be able to login using a combination of [`FlutterDriver.tap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/tap.html) and most importantly **[`FlutterDriver.enterText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/FlutterDriver/enterText.html)**.

Comment: This is cool and all but what about social login. How do you tap on -let's say- the first account when `google_sign_in` window appears?

Comment: @ErayErdin This is not currently possible to achieve using `flutter_driver`/`integration_test`.  See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34345.